# slideToggle opening all links on page?

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle

I am new to Javascript and am having a few issues with my toggle menu:

1) I set the sub links to `display:none;` but they are still displaying anyway. I need them to be hidden on page load.

2) When clicking one of the main links, it toggles both main links instead of just the one clicked on. What do I need to add so that only the clicked link opens?

http://jsfiddle.net/musiclvr86/5otvoxho/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of hack

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sub').slideToggle(0);
$('.main').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".main").slideToggle('fast');
});
});
```

and remove the line from your css

```
.dark-link.sub {display:none;  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5otvoxho/4/

Comment: Thank you. How would I use the `preventDefault()` in this scenario? When I tried using it, the page still jumps to the top when the link is clicked.

Comment: use event.preventDefault(); http://jsfiddle.net/5otvoxho/7/ (And i like upvotes ;) )

Comment: Thank you, that works great! Unfortunately I need 15 reputation before I can upvote. :(

Comment: I just noticed something strange. Whenever I add a link that doesn't need a sub menu, the sub menu "eats" the regular link below it. Any idea why it's doing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/5otvoxho/10/

Comment: I assume this is happening because the `nextUntil` method is selecting everything until "main" but what if I want it to stop when it gets to "main" or the standard "dark-link"?

Answer (score 0):

When you call it like this:

```
 $('.sub').slideToggle('fast');
```

You're targeting every element that has a `.sub` class, so all of them will toggle. To fix it, you have to subject the selection to the elements relative to the clicked one using `this`. Since, by your structure they are siblings, not parent/children, you may use the `.nextUntil()` method from Jquery:

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5otvoxho/2/)

```
$(this).nextUntil(".main").slideToggle('fast');
```

This will select every subsequent siblings, until it finds another `.main`

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about `nextUntil` method. Is it ok to use `return false;` to keep the page from jumping to the top when one of the links is clicked on? Or is there a better way to prevent that?